# Search/Replace date/time in file with Python

Tags: python, logging

I am building out a test environment that needs to have it's logs rolled to whenever the test is ran.  Basically, that means that if the logs were originally from [2010-05-16 13:45:23] we need to update the Year-Month-Date and also reflect the differences in time between then and now().  Next, the times are all different and need to maintain their order so that item #10 is older than item #200.

I have already tried to use the re module in python and line.replace.

```
import re
from datetime import date


##  Defines time variables
curyr = str(date.today().year)

##Declaring input/output files
inputfile = open('datetest.log', 'r')
outputfile = open('new_dtest.log', 'w')

for line in inputfile:
        outputfile.write(line.replace('2009', curyr))
##  Just trying to replace the year with the following:
##      outputfile.write(re.sub(r'\d\d\d\d', curyr, curyr)

##  Closing files
inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

As you can see, I'm not grabbing onto which module I can accomplish this with.  Any help is much appreciated.

The file 'datetest.log' is simply loaded with two test entries:

```
[2010-05-16 13:45:23]
[2011-06-17 14:55:33]
```

Comment: I don't get it, do you want to reformat the date/time or just sort lines based on the date/time?

Comment: @NickT We need to do both.  We need to replace the date/time so when we import the logs back into the systems it sees the events as current.  AND we will need to sort based on date/time since there was some order to the logs originally.  Basically, if the newest entry from the log file was from [2010-05-16 13:45:23], and today is [2013-11-08 15:20:48] we need to make the latest entry our current time.  And, if the second newest entry was [2010-05-16 10:30:20] then we need to make that entry the current YYMMDD then hour subtracted by the diff between entry 1 and entry 2, which is 15, and so on.

Comment: post a sample of the output.

Comment: The output of the file, as displayed above, is just the year changed. [2013-5-16...] instead of [2010-05-16].  But if I uncomment out the line using 're.sub' the output is the current year twice, but it deletes the MM and DD. Basically, it overwrites all other options.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, I would work in "datetime space" to construct your new log dates, and then convert them over to strings before you write them out, e.g.

```
For datetest.log with:
2011-06-17 14:55:33
2011-06-17 13:55:33
2011-06-17 12:55:33
2011-06-17 10:55:33
2011-06-17 07:55:33
2011-06-17 04:55:33
2011-06-17 01:55:33
====================

from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta as td

with open("datetest.log") as f:
    old = f.readlines()

sin = dt.strptime
sout = dt.strftime

# Convert your string data into datetime objects
format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
old_dt = [ sin(t.strip(), format) for t in old if t.strip() ]
# Get the time differences between your old date tags
old_diffs = [td(0.0)]
for i in range(1, len(old_dt) - 1):
    old_diffs.append( ( old_dt[i]- old_dt[i+1] ) + old_diffs[i-1])

# Use the current date as your new starting point, 
# and subtract off the old time diffs    
current_dt = dt.now()
new_dt = [ (current_dt - t) for t in old_diffs ]

# Convert back into strings for writing out
new = [sout(t, format) for t in new_dt]

new
['2013-11-08 14:19:02',
 '2013-11-08 13:19:02',
 '2013-11-08 11:19:02',
 '2013-11-08 08:19:02',
 '2013-11-08 05:19:02',
 '2013-11-08 02:19:02']
```

You can now write out `new` as your new log file.

Comment: thanks!  And thanks to everybody who has viewed and taken the time to consider this as well!